# First Data Payment Gateway Issue

Tags: php, curl, payment-gateway, firstdata

**I'm trying to intigrate First data Payment Getway in my site
Config file for FirstData Payment Gateway**

```
define("FDAPI_URL","https://ws.merchanttest.firstdataglobalgateway.com/fdggwsapi/services/order.wsdl");
define("FD_USERPWD","WSXXXXXXXX._.1:XXXXXXXX");
define("FD_SSLCERT", "/home/flagcases/domains/usaflagcases.com/public_html/certificate/WSXXXXXXXX._.1.pem"); 
define("FD_SSLKEY","/home/flagcases/domains/usaflagcases.com/public_html/certificate/WSXXXXXXXX._.1.key"); 
define("FD_SSLKEYPASSWD", "ckp_XXXXXXXX"); 
$ch = curl_init(FDAPI_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, FD_USERPWD);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, FD_SSLCERT);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, FD_SSLKEY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, FD_SSLKEYPASSWD);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
if ($result === false)
{
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
```

Alway I got Curl Error
**unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?) Curl Error**

Comment: Please try to add WSXXXXXXXX._.1.p12
might be help you... Where you added WSXXXXXXXX._.1.pem and WSXXXXXXXX._.1.key

Comment: where do I get the .p12 file?  I'm looking through the client administration pages and can't find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to add WSXXXXXXXX.*.1.p12 might be help you... Where you added WSXXXXXXXX.*.1.pem and WSXXXXXXXX._.1.key

Comment: How to use WSXXXXXXXX..1.p12, it use instead of WSXXXXXXXX..1.pem file ??